# Summarising survey data with surveySE from the Rmisc package to produce errorbars in ggplot

Tags: r, summary, survey, confidence-interval, standard-deviation

I am trying to group the following data so that I can use `summarySE` from the Rmisc package to later plot errorbars for this data. I have tried grouping in various ways but neither of my tries does what I want. For every different question I want to produce errorbars for the number of answers for different opinions.

Here is `my_data`, simplified but with the same structure:

```
structure(list(question = c("Item 1", "Item 1", "Item 1", "Item 1", 
"Item 2", "Item 2", "Item 2", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 3", "Item 3", 
"Item 3", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 4", "Item 4", "Item 4", "Item 4"
), opinion = c("A", "D", "N", "SA", "A", "D", "N", "SA", "A", 
"D", "N", "SA", "SD", "A", "D", "N", "SA", "SD"), number = c(13L, 
17L, 17L, 2L, 23L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 19L, 15L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 24L, 13L, 
7L, 3L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Here is the code I'm trying:

```
summary.unique <- summarySE(my_data, measurevar="number", groupvars=c("question", "opinion"))
```

which produces NaN:s, and this code

```
summary.unique <- summarySE(my_data, measurevar="number", groupvars=c( "opinion"))
```

just ignores the question column.

Comment: You've only got 1 observation per group, so the sd, se, and ci are all undefined.

Comment: Yes, but how should I do it? I need the summary for each different `opinion`, for each different "Item" in the `questions` column. `number` shows the amount of answers. If you are asking me to rearrange the data, I will do it if I just know how.

Comment: are you looking for error bars representing the uncertainties around proportions? (whether standard error or confidence intervals).  If not, what is the standard error that you are trying to calculate?

Comment: I am looking for the error bars to represent the uncertanities as 95% confidence intervals for the number of students that chose one out of each type of opinion, for each type of "Item" in the column `question`. I have a total of 49 survey participants and they all answered each survey question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
df$total = ave(df$number, df$question, FUN=sum)
df$proportion = df$number / df$total
cbind(df, mapply(x=df$number,y=df$total ,  \(x,y) binom.test(x,y)$conf.int) |> t())

    question opinion number total proportion          V1        V2
 1:   Item 1       A     13    49 0.26530612 0.149470729 0.4108171
 2:   Item 1       D     17    49 0.34693878 0.216724378 0.4963872
 3:   Item 1       N     17    49 0.34693878 0.216724378 0.4963872
 4:   Item 1      SA      2    49 0.04081633 0.004981842 0.1397872
 5:   Item 2       A     23    49 0.46938776 0.325338725 0.6172693
 6:   Item 2       D     10    49 0.20408163 0.102449385 0.3434300
 7:   Item 2       N     11    49 0.22448980 0.117743421 0.3662430
 8:   Item 2      SA      5    49 0.10204082 0.033971705 0.2222767
 9:   Item 3       A     19    49 0.38775510 0.251974483 0.5376145
10:   Item 3       D     15    49 0.30612245 0.182519448 0.4541524
11:   Item 3       N      6    49 0.12244898 0.046289031 0.2476930
12:   Item 3      SA      5    49 0.10204082 0.033971705 0.2222767
13:   Item 3      SD      4    49 0.08163265 0.022690881 0.1960142
14:   Item 4       A     24    49 0.48979592 0.344247423 0.6366217
15:   Item 4       D     13    49 0.26530612 0.149470729 0.4108171
16:   Item 4       N      7    49 0.14285714 0.059421506 0.2724215
17:   Item 4      SA      3    49 0.06122449 0.012808421 0.1686589
18:   Item 4      SD      2    49 0.04081633 0.004981842 0.1397872
```

`V1` and `V2` are your upper and lower 95% confidence limits for each row.

To break it down, the first two lines simply generate the total per question and the the proportion.  The second uses `mapply` on the dataframe to apply `binom.test` to each row, specifying that `number` is the `x` and `total` is the `n` argument for `binom.test`.  The confidence interval is extracted and then `t()` is used to transpose the output into the correct shape.